# Unable to connect to PostgreSQL from CakePHP

Tags: php, postgresql, cakephp

I'm getting errors in my PHP when I try and connect to a postgres datasource.

```
> Error: Database connection "Postgres" is missing, or could not be created.
#0 /var/www/html/api/lib/Cake/Model/ConnectionManager.php(105): DboSource->__construct(Array)
#1 /var/www/html/api/lib/Cake/Model/Model.php(3482): ConnectionManager::getDataSource('nuvi')
#2 /var/www/html/api/lib/Cake/Model/Model.php(1128): Model->setDataSource('nuvi')
#3 /var/www/html/api/lib/Cake/Model/Model.php(3504): Model->setSource('reports')
#4 /var/www/html/api/lib/Cake/Model/Model.php(3311): Model->getDataSource()
#5 /var/www/html/api/app/Model/NuviReport.php(1172): Model->query('SELECT `rtg`.`m...')
#6 /var/www/html/api/app/Model/NuviReport.php(911): NuviReport->setMetrics('4778')
#7 /var/www/html/api/app/Console/Command/ReportsShell.php(42): NuviReport->setReportMetrics('4778')
#8 /var/www/html/api/lib/Cake/Console/Shell.php(440): ReportsShell->main()
#9 /var/www/html/api/lib/Cake/Console/ShellDispatcher.php(207): Shell->runCommand(NULL, Array)
#10 /var/www/html/api/lib/Cake/Console/ShellDispatcher.php(66): ShellDispatcher->dispatch()
#11 /var/www/html/api/app/Console/cake.php(36): ShellDispatcher::run(Array)
```

I can connect ok to a MySQL database but get errors  when Im trying to switch to postgres

The output from php -v is

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/mysqli' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/mysqli: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/pdo_mysql' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/pdo_mysql: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/var/lib/php5/modules/registry/pdo_pgsql' - /var/lib/php5/modules/registry/pdo_pgsql: file too short in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/var/lib/php5/modules/registry/pgsql' - /var/lib/php5/modules/registry/pgsql: file too short in Unknown on line 0
PHP 5.6.30 (cli) (built: Mar 21 2017 23:01:57) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
```

Ive installed apt-get install php5-pgsql and thats got some of the modules I was missing so my php.ini modules now looks like this

```
;extension=bz2
;extension=curl
;extension=fileinfo
;extension=gd2
;extension=gettext
;extension=gmp
;extension=intl
;extension=imap
;extension=interbase
;extension=ldap
;extension=mbstring
;extension=exif      ; Must be after mbstring as it depends on it
extension=mysqli
extension=/usr/lib/php5/20131226/mysqli.so
;extension=oci8_12c  ; Use with Oracle Database 12c Instant Client
;extension=openssl
;extension=pdo_firebird
extension=pdo_mysql
;extension=pdo_oci
;extension=pdo_odbc
extension=/var/lib/php5/modules/registry/pdo_pgsql
;extension=pdo_sqlite
extension=/var/lib/php5/modules/registry/pgsql
;extension=shmop
```

I'm not seeing anything about postgres in php -i but there is just this

PDO

PDO support => enabled
PDO drivers => sqlite, mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well now dont I feel like a slapped arse. Spent all day faffing about with postgres and unbuntu only to realise that Ive left the .so off of the file names

updated the php.ini to the following if anyone else makes the same mistake

```
extension=/var/lib/php5/modules/registry/pdo_pgsql.so
extension=/var/lib/php5/modules/registry/pgsql.so
```